# Maximum subscriber nodes that can be configured in SQL Server 2012 Merge Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, replication

How many max subscriber nodes can be configured in merge replication in MS SQL server 2012 ?

Is there any limit as such ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard limit but you will limited by hardware considering the agents will consume cpu, memory, and i/o.  There is also a desktop heap issue that some have run into when running a large number of subscriptions, ymmv.

Comment: Given what a modern computer can look like (36 cores in 2 sockets, 1.x tb of RAM) that is a quite high limit, though ;)